# Overlay image on top of the video

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mplayer

I am looking to play a video with an overlay image. Though with the help of `ffmpeg` I was able to make a new video with the overlay image.

Reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38753739/ffmpeg-overlay-a-png-image-on-a-video-with-custom-transparency).

But is there any other way without converting the video before playing it, and playing the video separately and overlaying the image on top of it.

Comment: This is not an Ubuntu question. You should find a video-editing forum.  That said, I do not know of any video player that combines video streams in realtime.  You can always overlay subtitles but those are strictly limited to text.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mpv`. This example will overlay `video.mp4` as the background and `image.png` as the foreground. `image.png` will be placed in the lower right with a 10px padding.

```
mpv --lavfi-complex="[vid1][vid2]overlay=W-w-10:H-h-10[vo]" video.mp4 --external-file=image.png
```

See the [overlay filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay) and [`mpv` documentation](https://mpv.io/manual/) for more info.